# Rails 6 + Webpacker + Yarn: problem to load javascript libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg, webpacker, alertifyjs

I'm having trouble to configure javascript library's on rails 6 using webpacker and yarn. I tried with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) and [alertifyjs](https://alertifyjs.com) but both returned the same error for me, Idk where is my error.

For example:
I tried to add an alert library to my project. I did the following steps:

```
yarn add alertifyjs
```

I added require in application.js:

```
require ('alertifyjs');
```

In my application.html.erb, the javascript pack tag are in:

```
<% = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
```

If I enter in the page and see the rendered JS file along with the page, the **alertifyjs** code is there, but when trying to instantiate a new alert, I get the following error:

```
alertify.alert('Ready!');
```

**ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: alertify**

The same occurred with momentjs.

My nodemodules folder hierarchy after yard add alertifyjs:
[alertifyjs folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs1J3.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem!

I was missing to import and put the variable global to be able to access outside of the application.js

```
import alertify from 'alertifyjs';
global.alertify = alertify;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `var alertify = require ('alertifyjs');` ?

Comment: I added _var alertify = require('alertifyjs');_ on my application.js file but the error: _ReferenceError: Can't find variable: alertify continues,

Comment: even do that just below the declaration?